# Google App Engine - How to add static files to a war folder of a running GAE application without a redeploy

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to create an application where I host a few static html files that a user authors and uploads to GAE.

Is it possible to upload these files to WAR folder for hosting without a redeploy.

Uploading to WAR may not be a good idea as a redeploy would wipe out the user authored files. Would like these files to be stored across deployments.

May be a GCS bucket ? But in case of GCS bucket, how would you serve these static html files over a GAE/page.html url ?

I was reading that GCS bucket would serve as a web folder by turning a knob on that bucket. But how scalable would that be ? Is that even a good approach to use GCS bucket as a web url ?

Would be good to get some ideas on addressing this as I am new to GAE ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use Google Cloud Storage to serve static websites](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration?hl=en) and a Google AppEngine application to update the bucket when user edit/upload some content to the website.

You would probably need to have different subdomains for this like:

- www.example.com - GCS
- admin.example.com - GAE app that manages uploading/editing files using [GCS API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets?hl=en).

This should be pretty scalable & cheap to serve traffic.

Apart from GCS you also can considering storing static files on [Amazon S](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)3 or any other hosting that has API. Actually you even can develop a solution that upload files to multiple storages like GCS, S3, etc. and serve them using fault-tolerant DNS or reverse-proxy (like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)) so if Google or Amazon goes down your website is up and running.

Comment: Hi Alexander ! Thanks for the info. I was able to get it working this way. Can you please add your thoughts on how to restrict / authenticate only a select set of users to access a bucket hosted as a site ? I see that the moment u convert the bucket to a site, it becomes public. Well, that's expected for a website to be public. But I would be creating different sites for different set of users and want to restrict access that way. Any thoughts ?  Users would be loading these html files from phone gap

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en
and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html